# Comparing corresponding cells in different ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, compare, range, cells

I want to be able to compare each cell in a range say B1:B10 with the corresponding cell in another range, say C1:C10 and count the cells that match a criteria like if B1 >= C1, and if B2 >= C2, and if B3 >= C3 and so on.

Comment: Have you looked at the [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function? Criteria can be an expression, like ">=", which seems to suit your needs. If not, perhaps you can shed some light in formula's and functions you have tried already?

Comment: I did look into the COUNTIF, but it seems to be only counting my text cells (which I definitely don't want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

**=SUMPRODUCT(--((B1:B10)>=(C1:C10)))**

**EDIT#1:**

This version will exclude text cells:

**=SUMPRODUCT(--((B1:B10)>=(C1:C10))*ISNUMBER(B1:B10)*ISNUMBER(C1:C10))**

Comment: Sorry Gary's Student, I misunderstood the use of the SUMPRODUCT function. However, I tried as you suggested and it only returned a count of my text cells.

Comment: Upon closer inspection it appears to be working, but also including the text cells. How do you suggest tweaking the formula to avoid including the text cells?.

Comment: Jackpot! Thanks @Gary'sStudent! Worked like a charm!